# Как вызвать фрагмент из другого фрагмента, который был вызван из активити?

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity, fragment-transaction

Пытаюсь разобраться как правильно построить архитектуру. В данный момент у меня есть `MainActivity` из которого могут вызываются фрагменты. Вот метод который открывает фрагмент из активити:

```
private void showFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction
                .replace(R.id.container_fragment, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
```

Далее, если я хочу открыть следующий фрагмент из фрагмента, я попробовал использовать этот же метод, но получается что открывается и страница нового фрагмента, и активити, т.е. они смешиваются и получается 2 наложенных страницы.

P.S. использую библиотеку `butterknife`, но думаю это не влияет на смешивание двух страниц, либо есть способ как решить эту задачу, либо лучше использовать другое архитектурное решение.

Вот такой пример:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @BindView(R.id.text_sign_in)
    TextView textSignIn;
    @BindView(R.id.text_sign_up)
    TextView textSignUp;
    @BindView(R.id.container_sign_in_sign_up)
    FrameLayout containerSignInSignUp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        textSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
        textSignUp.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.text_sign_in:
                SignInFragment signInFragment = new SignInFragment();
                showFragment(signInFragment);
                break;
            case R.id.text_sign_up:
                SignUpFragment signUpFragment = new SignUpFragment();
                showFragment(signUpFragment);
                break;
        }
    }

    // тут вызываем первый фрагмент
    private void showFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction
                .replace(R.id.container_sign_in_sign_up, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (!VKSdk.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new VKCallback<VKAccessToken>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(VKAccessToken res) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Congrats: Login Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent welcome = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(welcome);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(VKError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Didn't pass Authorization", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        })) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

макет активити:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login_offer"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_x" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_sign_in"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:text="@string/login_offer_sign_in"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_x" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_sign_up"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/login_offer_sign_up"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_x" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_sign_in_sign_up"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Это первый фрагмент который вызывается из активити:

```
 public class SignInFragment extends BaseFragment {
        public static final String TAG = SignInFragment.class.getSimpleName();

        @BindView(R.id.sign_in_vk)
        Button signInVk;
        @BindView(R.id.editTextUserEmail)
        EditText editTextUserEmail;
        @BindView(R.id.editTextPassword)
        EditText editTextPassword;
        @BindView(R.id.sign_in)
        Button signIn;
        @BindView(R.id.link_forgot_password)
        TextView linkForgotPassword;

        Unbinder unbinder;

        private MainActivity activityParent;
        private LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;

        public SignInFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);

            if (activity instanceof MainActivity) {
                activityParent = (MainActivity) activity;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            assert rootView != null;
            unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            loginDataBaseAdapter = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(activityParent);
            loginDataBaseAdapter = loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

            signInVk.setOnClickListener(v -> VKSdk.login(activityParent));
            signIn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                String userEmail = editTextUserEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                String storedPassword = loginDataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(userEmail);

                if (password.equals(storedPassword)) {
                    showToast(getText(R.string.account_greeting));
                    Intent welcome = new Intent(activityParent, WelcomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(welcome);
                } else {
                    showToast(getText(R.string.account_invalid));
                }
            });

            linkForgotPassword.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Fragment fragment = new RecoveryPasswordFragment();
                showFragment(fragment);
            });
        }
    // тут вызываем второй фрагмент
    private void showFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction
                .replace(R.id.container_sign_in_sign_up, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResourceId() {
        return R.layout.fragment_sign_in;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
        unbinder.unbind();
    }
}
```

А это второй фрагмент:

```
public class RecoveryPasswordFragment extends BaseFragment {
    public static final String TAG = RecoveryPasswordFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    @BindView(R.id.text_recover_password_title)
    TextView textRecoverPasswordTitle;
    @BindView(R.id.text_recover_password_description)
    TextView textRecoverPasswordDescription;
    @BindView(R.id.edit_recover_password)
    EditText editRecoverPassword;

    Unbinder unbinder;

    public RecoveryPasswordFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recovery_password, container, false);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResourceId() {
        return R.layout.fragment_recovery_password;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        unbinder.unbind();
    }
}
```

Comment: butterknife тут ни при чём :) Покажите весь код активити и фрагмента, так будет проще Вам помочь.

Comment: @Vitaly Tomashevsky да конечно обновил=)